# Upstart and isstty(STDOUT_FILENO)

Tags: upstart, redirect, stdout

Many Linux programs use [`istty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) to determine whether STDOUT is a terminal or not. For example, `ls` will (by default) suppress coloured output if it's redirected (`istty == 0`).

When running upstart jobs, STDOUT does not appear to be redirected. The process thinks it's writing to `/dev/pts/0`.

My application uses this same deductive approach and, under upstart, outputs terminal control characters which end up in the log files in `/var/log/upstart/myapp.log`.

Can I either configure the upstart job or modify my (C++) application's source to fix this issue?

(It's not just control characters, but also things like timestamps are omitted from console output but included in log files.)

Answer (score 0):

Having your program behave differently depending on what it is connected to is frowned upon. For example, [the GNU Coding Standards say](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/User-Interfaces.html#User-Interfaces):

> Likewise, please don’t make the behavior of a command-line program
>   depend on the type of output device it gets as standard output or
>   standard input. Device independence is an important principle of the
>   system’s design; do not compromise it merely to save someone from
>   typing an option now and then. (Variation in error message syntax when
>   using a terminal is ok, because that is a side issue that people do
>   not depend on.)

Instead, consider adding command line options to your program to change behaviour, and using these in your upstart job.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing, however many GNU applications make their _default_ behaviour depend upon output device, providing options when you wish to be explicit.